# django-cms: implementing a hierarchy-attached product list

Tags: python, django, django-cms, django-mptt

I am considering using django-cms to implement the following scenario:

1. Admins can create hierarchical pages, e.g.:

cosmetics
cosmetics/toothbrushes
cosmetics/toothbrushes/electric

1. In a separate interface, you can administrate the corresponding products, and attach them to any of the levels in the page tree.

e.g.
Dr. Best, ToothFairy -> attached to cosmetics/toothbrushes
Braun Oral-B -> attached to cosmetics/toothbrushes/electric

1. If a frontend user navigates to cosmetics/toothbrushes/electric, they will see a listing containing both Dr. Best and ToothFairy
2. If a frontend user navigates to cosmetics/toothbrushes, they will see a listing containing all three products (i.e. the products attached to the corresponding level and all descendants).
3. Products are attached to the page-id, not the full path (slug/slug/slug)

Having no experience with django-cms I am wondering what approach is best for this. I have looked at the docs for custom plugins and app integration but am unsure what approach to follow, or if that is even possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into django-shop. It is a project written by the same guys who wrote django-cms, and they are taking the same, super extensible approach to shopping carts as CMS.

To get started on integration, have a look at the fantastic integration work currently being done by [Airtonix](http://github.com/airtonix/)